# How add SSL/443 to Apache server without virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, httpd, httpd.conf, apache-2.4

I have an apache server set up on CentOS. I am trying to add SSL. I was able to create the certificate and keys and then updated `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` to have the following configurations:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf**

```
#Where I put my cert
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt

#where I put my key
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
```

Then I updated `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
Listen 443
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
```

Then I ran `service httpd restart` and I get the error:

```
Stopping httpd:          [OK]
Starting httpd:          (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
                         [OK]
```

What do I need to do to enable SSL?

Comment: It looks like Apache's complaining that another service is already listening on 443; what's the output of `sudo netstat -lnp`? Also verify that there isn't another directive elsewhere in your Apache config that has it listening on that port.

Comment: @Kromey yes, I discovered that the ssl.conf file had a `Listen 443` directive. thanks!

Comment: are you sure the setting in httpd.conf will always override ssl.conf? previously i added SSL allowed protocol to excludes TLS1 at httpd.conf, but it doesnt work until i  do the same in the ssl.conf. it looks like ssl.conf somehow affected httpd.conf instead of ssl.conf is always overrided by httpd.conf

Comment: @SKLTFZ you read my comment backwards. i said ssl.conf is the one that wins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, in CentOS, there is a file used by Apache/httpd located at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`. This file is read in as a configuration by Apache along with the "httpd.conf" file and anything in it takes precedence over settings in `httpd.conf`.

That file (again by default) contains a `Listen 443` directive. You cannot call that directive twice (as it will say it's already been bound to that port), so that caused the conflict. After removing that, it works.

Comment: @krisFR I explained it as fully as I can. Please remove your downvote if it answers your questions.

Comment: Will remove my comment (done), will not remove downvote as it is not from me...But +1 for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody stumbles over this question in 2017...

There is no need to edit `httpd.conf` since `ssl.conf` contains all the directives we need:

```
# When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the 
# the HTTPS port in addition.
#
Listen 443 https
```

...

```
#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
```

And of course the paths to the certs:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/<mycert>.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/<mykey>.key
```

In other words, it is enough to add the information in `ssl.conf` and the restart the `httpd` service. Of course, this only works if this (the last) line:

```
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

...is uncommented as per above in the file `httpd.conf`, which it is in a default installation.

System info:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
```

Answer (score 0):

## On Debian bases Systems or usually on generally other

Create

- /etc/apache2/conf-available/default-ssl.conf

  ```
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
                Listen 443

  </IfModule>
  ```

This Works out of the Box, in case you want to use the default page i.e. for Reverse-Proxy with NGINX or Other.

Its not limited to a VHOST.

#### Additional Information

It will not Produce an error due the fact, it only works when Mod-SSL is enabled.

```sh
bash:# a2enmod ssl
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
Module setenvif already enabled
Considering dependency mime for ssl:
Module mime already enabled
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
Enabling module socache_shmcb.
Enabling module ssl.
See /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz on how to configure SSL and create self-signed certificates.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2
```

Remind to restart Apache

```sh
Bash:# lsof -i :443
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 1337       root    6u  IPv6 488893      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2 13337  www-data    6u  IPv6 488893      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2 133337 www-data    6u  IPv4 488893      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

This works for me since ages.